# Ternary with extends inside index type query with partial?

Tags: typescript

Could someone walk me through what's happening here? I honestly can't make heads or tails of how this code is resulting in a type declaration.

```
type SettingsModalErrors = Partial<
  {
    [k in keyof GroupInput]: GroupInput[k] extends SomeProduct
      ? PaywallSettingsErrors
      : DefaultError
  }
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html).

So to break this type declaration down:

- `type SettingsModalErrors =` is a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases), so that `SettingsModalErrors` can be referenced elsewhere as a type.
- `Partial<>` is a built-in [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that makes the input type have all optional fields. So `Partial<{ a: string }>` becomes `{ a?: string }`.
- The `{ }` is an inline structural type definition.
- `[k in keyof GroupInput]` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (similar but not the same as an [index type signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures)) that says all the keys of `GroupInput` are keys of the resulting type. So if `GroupInput` is `{ text: string }` then `[k in keyof GroupInput]: number` results in `{ text: number }`
- `GroupInput[k]` is an [index type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), using `k` from the mapped key to lookup the type of that key on the `GroupInput` type. So in other words `{ [k in keyof GroupInput]: GroupInput[k] }` results in effectively the same type as `GroupInput`.
- `GroupInput[k] extends SomeProduct ? PaywallSettingsErrors : DefaultError` is the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), which operates with the same logic as a native JS ternary statement. What it means is that if the type of `GroupInput[k]` can be assigned to `SomeProduct` then make the type (in this case a key of the resulting mapped type) `PaywallSettingsErrors`, otherwise make the type `DefaultError`. By itself a conditional type just defines are single type. Used on the right-side of a mapped type expression as in this case it's being applied to each key of the mapped type.

Example in [the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20SomeProduct%20%3D%20%7B%20product%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20PaywallSettingsErrors%20%3D%20%7B%20errors%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20DefaultError%20%3D%20%7B%20error%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20GroupInput%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20SomeProduct%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20SettingsModalErrors%20%3D%20Partial%3C%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bk%20in%20keyof%20GroupInput%5D%3A%20GroupInput%5Bk%5D%20extends%20SomeProduct%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20PaywallSettingsErrors%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20DefaultError%0A%7D%3E%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Mouse%20over%20%60SettingsModalErrors%60%20above%3A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20type%20SettingsModalErrors%20%3D%20%7B%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20PaywallSettingsErrors%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20bar%3F%3A%20DefaultError%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%7D).

Given these types:

```
type SomeProduct = { product: string };

type PaywallSettingsErrors = { errors: any };

type DefaultError = { error: any };

type GroupInput = {
    foo: SomeProduct;
    bar: number;
}
```

If you then run the code you described:

```
type SettingsModalErrors = Partial<
  {
    [k in keyof GroupInput]: GroupInput[k] extends SomeProduct
      ? PaywallSettingsErrors
      : DefaultError
  }
>
```

Then the resulting type of `SettingsModalErrors` is:

```
type SettingsModalErrors = {
    foo?: PaywallSettingsErrors;
    bar?: DefaultError;
}
```

The `?` is thanks to `Partial<>`, the keys `foo` and `bar` are thanks to the mapped type `[k in keyof GroupInput]`, and the types `PaywallSettingsErrors` and `DefaultError` on those keys are thanks to the conditional type expression.

Comment: "So in other words { [k in keyof GroupInput]: GroupInput[k] } results in effectively the same type as GroupInput." --> if I've understood you right, I can actually literally replace that section with just `GroupInput extends SomeProduct ? PaywallSettingsErrors : DefaultError`. Is that right?

Comment: No... you need the mapped-type to remap the keys of `GroupInput` into the same keys but with a different type, the conditional type is the logic as to how each key gets its new type. `{ [k in keyof GroupInput]: GroupInput[k] }` by itself could just be replaced with `GroupInput`, but its the conditional type that makes it useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
type SettingsModalErrors = Partial<
```

it creates a type with all properties optional

```
{
    [k in keyof GroupInput]:
```

and property names are the same as in the `GroupInput` type

```
           GroupInput[k] extends SomeProduct
       ? PaywallSettingsErrors
       : DefaultError
```

and property types depend on the type of corresponding `GroupInput` property. If it's `SomeProduct` or a subtype of `SomeProduct`, the property type is `PaywallSettingsErrors`, otherwise the property type is `DefaultError`.

> how this code is resulting in a type declaration

It starts with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which generally looks like

```
{[k in keyof SomeType]: SomePropertyType}
```

In your case, `SomePropertyType` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) which depends on the `GroupInput[k]` which is a type of property named `k` in `GroupInput`, with `k` going over all property names in `keyof GroupInput`.

And then it's wrapped with built-in [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) type.

Comment: So is it saying that if anything in `GroupInput` extends `SomeProduct`, then partial `PaywallSettingsErrors`, otherwise partial `DefaultError`?

Comment: No the `Partial` wraps the whole mapped type, making all properties optional - basically either `PaywallSettingErrors` or `DefaultError` or undefined. The property type is the "whole" `...Error` if the property is present.